# MVC4 Unit test: Cannot insert duplicate key in object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, unit-testing, ef-code-first

I'm writing a unit test for an application and I get this error but only when running my test.

```
Test method Tests.Items.CreateItem.CreateNewItem threw exception: 
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Items'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Items'. The duplicate key value is (e13b11ae-762f-4b86-84b3-d8224fcd84c9).
The statement has been terminated.
Result StackTrace:  
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.<Update>b__2(UpdateTranslator ut)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update[T](T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__35()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<SaveChangesInternal>b__27()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
    at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges()
   at System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges()
```

This is my unit test:

```
[TestClass]
public class CreateItem
{
    Guid guiItemID = Guid.Parse("e13b11ae-762f-4b86-84b3-d8224fcd84c9");

    [TestMethod]
    public void CreateNewItem()
    {
        // Create element
        Item item = new Item();
        item.ID = guiItemID;

        // Save element to database
        TestContext db = new TestContext();
        db.Items.Add(item);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

This is the ID property on my model:

```
[Key]
public Guid ID { get; set; }
```

If I run the same code from my seed method the database is seeded with this item. So I know the code for interacting with the database works correctly.

If I change:

```
item.ID = guiItemID;
```

to:

```
item.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Then the test passes. But I want to set the ID so I can test other things by retrieving the same item later.

My item does not exist already in the database. This is an empty database.

Why does my test throw an error as if the Item already exists when it clearly doesn't? Is the test running twice somehow? It's the only test in my list.

Comment: Are you blowing your database away on the teardown of your test suite? If not.. then whatever you put into the database during your test will remain there for the next time you run your tests..

Comment: Side note: normally test working with DB would not be called "unit test", but rather integration test. For unit tests you'll mock DB dependency...

Comment: Double side note: Anything that tests actual (non-mocked) dependencies between modules is called an Integration test. Whether that be a database, or even just another class. Unit tests test a single unit of code in isolation from other dependencies (where those dependencies are mocked).

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Nothing is appearing in the database at any point during the test run. How might I be blowing away the database?

Comment: @Jon If you change the string GUID slightly.. can you run your test at least once? Does it fail the second time you try and run it?

Comment: Hmm, yes, it does run once if I change the GUID slightly. However I'm not seeing anything in my database and I just double checked my connection string, and it's pointing to the correct place. If I make changes to the Model or add items using the seed method then I see them. What's different for my test?

Comment: @jon,for UT a separate database every time you run, now if you stop test case in between then sometimes database which is created doesn't get deleted. Recommended way to write your test is to have a test cleanup[TestCleanup] method and do cleanup activity

Answer (score 1):

UT a separate database every time you run, now if you stop test case in between then sometimes database which is created doesn't get deleted. Recommended way to write your test is to have a test cleanup[TestCleanup] method and do cleanup activity

```
  [TestCleanup]
  public void TestCleanup()
  {
       var entity = db.Item.Find(guiItemID);
       db.Item.Remove(entity);
       db.SaveChanges();
  }
```